# When is an Explicit Add-Type Call Required for a System DLL in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-core

While writing a PowerShell script that uses items in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`, I noticed a discrepancy between when my script runs on PowerShell Desktop vs PowerShell Core.

This command works on PowerShell Core without explicit assembly loads:

```bsh
$context = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new(
    [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, 
    $Domain)
```

However, the exact same command fails on PowerShell Classic with:

```
Unable to find type [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext].
```

However, if I manually load the type (via `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`), it works fine on PowerShell Classic.

What's striking me as odd is my script uses plenty of other .NET Assemblies, all of which load fine without an explicit `Add-Type` call, in both Classic and Core.

Is there a clear set of rules for which assemblies must be imported via `Add-Type` vs which can be implicitly loaded?

Comment: I have, unfortunately, never been able to determine the answer to this question. As far as I can tell, PowerShell automatically imports the necessary assemblies for the loaded modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this issue in the PowerShell docs repo: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6422#issuecomment-668293431

- In Windows PowerShell (i.e. 5.1 and below), you need to use Add-Type for anything that isn't already loaded. This is chiefly for scenarios involving GAC assemblies, which you can specify by name, rather than by path.
- In PS 6+, there is no GAC. But PowerShell now ships its own assemblies in $PSHome. These assemblies are automatically loaded on request, so there's no need to Add-Type them, but doing so is still permitted (it allows you to write scripts that are implicitly compatible with Windows PowerShell, like the example you give above).
- Since there's no GAC, there's no actual need in PS 6+ to use Add-Type
- Loading assemblies from arbitrary paths still requires Add-Type, since those assemblies will not be discovered otherwise

It looks like the PowerShell documentation will be updated with the new information.